# How to make ordinary krigging with a spherical variogram in SAGA GIS?

Tags: saga, kriging, variogram

I have a very special map to make: it's a sea bird density map. To do this, I interpolate the observation points with ordinary kriging with a variogram. As I've read, the variogram must be of "spherical" type. The default one in SAGA is linear, but one can modify the equation. My question is: which equation should I use?

[image: Variogram equations]

Comment: You can find the equation of the Spherical model for example here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variogram#Variogram_models. I think the last option from the drop-down menu is what you're looking for. But better check for yourself, I tend to make mistakes looking at equations written in this form.

Comment: @Janina Will you post your comment as answer? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the equation of the Spherical model for example on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variogram#Variogram_models):

[image]

I think the last option from the drop-down menu is what you're looking for.